# Trying to show $ \sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty }{ \frac { \left( 2n \right) ! }{ { 2 }^{ n } } } { x }^{ n }\quad$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series

So we have

$$ \sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { \left( 2n \right) ! }{ { 2 }^{ n } }  } { x }^{ n }\quad ={ \quad a }_{ n } $$

Using the ratio test

$$\lim _{ n->\infty  }{ \left( \left| \frac { { a }_{ n+1 } }{ { \quad a }_{ n } }  \right|  \right)  }  $$

Then I get

$$ \lim _{ n->\infty  }{ \left( \left| \frac { \frac { \left( 2n+1 \right) ! }{ { 2 }^{ n+1 } } { x }^{ n+1 } }{ \frac { \left( 2n \right) ! }{ { 2 }^{ n } } { x }^{ n } }  \right|  \right)  }  $$

So where I am having  an issue is taking this expression

$$ \frac { \frac { \left( 2n+1 \right) ! }{ { 2 }^{ n+1 } } { x }^{ n+1 } }{ \frac { \left( 2n \right) ! }{ { 2 }^{ n } } { x }^{ n } } $$

And rewriting it so that it is clear how to take the limit

Comment: Two things: (1) you want $[2(n+1)]!$, not $(2n+1)!$; there's a difference between these expressions.  (2) What is $(2n+2)!/(2n)!$ ?

Comment: It converges if $x=0$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \left| \frac { { a }_{ n+1 } }{ { \quad a }_{ n } }  \right| = } \lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \left| \frac { \frac { \left( 2n+2 \right) ! }{ { 2 }^{ n+1 } } \quad { x }^{ n+1 } }{ \frac { \left( 2n \right) ! }{ { 2 }^{ n } } { x }^{ n } }  \right| = } \lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \left| \frac { \left( 2n+1 \right) \left( 2n+2 \right)  }{ 2 }  \right| \left| x \right| = } +\infty ,x\neq 0\\ $$

Comment: No, it $a_{n+1} = \frac{(2(n+1))!}{2^{n+1}} x^{n+1}$.

Comment: $2(n+1) = 2n+2$.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac { \frac { \left( 2n+1 \right) ! }{ { 2 }^{ n+1 } } { x }^{ n+1 } }{ \frac { \left( 2n \right) ! }{ { 2 }^{ n } } { x }^{ n } } =\frac {(2n+1)!}{(2n)!}\frac{2^n}{2^{n+1}}\frac{x^{n+1}}{x^n} =  \frac {(2n+1)x}{2}$

However, as SpamIam points out

$a_{n+1} = \frac {(2n+2)! x^n}{2^n}$

and

$\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac { \frac { \left( 2n+2 \right) ! }{ { 2 }^{ n+1 } } { x }^{ n+1 } }{ \frac { \left( 2n \right) ! }{ { 2 }^{ n } } { x }^{ n } }= (n+1)(2n+1)x$

Comment: No, it $a_{n+1} = \frac{(2(n+1))!}{2^{n+1}} x^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

You have a small mistake in your expression for $a_{n+1}$.  Also, it's usually easier to write $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ by writing the expression for $a_n$ "upside-down."
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| &= \left|\frac{(2(n+1))!}{2^{n+1}} x^{n+1} \cdot \frac{2^n}{(2n)! x^n}\right| = |x| \frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)!}{2 (2n)!}\\
&= |x| \frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{2} \to \infty
\end{align*}
as $n \to \infty$ unless $x = 0$.